# How to get radio button selection with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC html control for radiobutton like:

```
 <%= Html.RadioButton("Choice", false, new { onclick = "Accept()" })%><label for="Choice">Yes</label>
 <%= Html.RadioButton("Choice", false, new { onclick = "Deny()" })%><label for="Choice">No</label>
```

How to get radio button selection with JQuery?

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea what the html will look like that your code makes. But, you can use this code to get each **radio button's value**. you can write a more specific selector yourself.

```
$("input:radio").each(function(){
 if($(this).is(":checked")){
   var val = this.value;
 } else {
   //not checked. do something else.
 }
});
```

or get all the radios that are **checked**:

```
$("input:radio:checked").each(function() {
   var value = this.value;
   //do something with value of checked radiobox
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understand is right, second parameter must be object's value, and third parameter is checked state.

so, it must be.

```
 <%= Html.RadioButton("Choice", "Yes", false, new { onclick = "Accept()" })%><label for="Choice">Yes</label>
 <%= Html.RadioButton("Choice", "No", false, new { onclick = "Deny()" })%><label for="Choice">No</label>
```

then you can select by jquery.

```
$("Choice[value='Yes']").attr("checked", true);
```

**Update:** or if you want to get a value.

```
var yes = $("Choice[value='Yes']).val();
```

Comment: this will set a radio button to be checked. i dont think that is what he wanted

Answer (score 0):

I believe the selected values are not available until a postback on the server. This is why irrespect of what radio-button you select from the group, the value in jquery always comes as the default selected. The easiest way to get aroung this issue is to enclose the radio button inside a 'div' and then find out if the radio-button inside the 'div' is checked or not. Something like this:

```
    <div id="div1">
     <%= Html.RadioButton("Choice", false, new { onclick = "Accept()" })%><label for="Choice">Yes</label></div>
     <div id="div2">
 <%= Html.RadioButton("Choice", false, new { onclick = "Deny()" })%><label for="Choice">No</label></div>
```

and then

```
if($("#div1").find("input[type="radio"]").is(":checked"))
   // 1st radio button is checked
else if($("#div2").find("input[type="radio"]").is(":checked"))
   // 2nd radio button is checked
```